# Optimize iteration throught numpy array

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, iteration, loops

I'm swapping values of a multidimensional numpy array in Python. But the code is too slow. Another thread says:

> Typically, you avoid iterating through them directly. ... there's a good chance that it's easy to vectorize.

So, do you know a way to optimize the following code?

```
import PIL.Image
import numpy

pil_image = PIL.Image.open('Image.jpg').convert('RGB')
cv_image = numpy.array(pil_image)
# Convert RGB to BGR
for y in range(len(cv_image)):
    for x in range(len(cv_image[y])):
        (cv_image[y][x][0], cv_image[y][x][2]) = (cv_image[y][x][2],
            cv_image[y][x][0])
```

For an 509x359 image this last more than one second, which is way too much. It should perform it's task in no time.

Comment: on a side note, `cv_image[y][x][0]` is generally written `cv_image[y, x, 0]` in numpy/python.

Comment: Thanks. Now it only lasts 0.406 seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this single operation inverting the matrix along the last axis?

```
cv_image = cv_image[:,:,::-1]
```

Comment: There's something strange with this. Both types (source and result) are `numpy.ndarray`. When iterating through them and comparing `len(...)` or the values (reversely), there can't be found a difference. But when trying to show the image with `cv2.imshow` it says: `error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type` (while without the conversion the image is displayed [with wrong colors]).

Comment: I use the line: `new_cv_image = cv_image[:, :, ::-1]`. If I change one value in cv_image: `cv_image[0, 0, 2] = 128`, it is also changed in new_cv_image, although `id(...)` returns a different value for each.

Comment: You could try `cv_image = cv_image[..., ::-1].copy()`. imshow is probably expecting a continuous array in memory.

Comment: @Bago: I came to the same conclusion (source: http://mbk.ps.uci.edu/python.html , search "copy"). This works perfectly well! I measured 0.0 seconds (no time). I would say: Goal achieved.